# AngularJs How to generalize common functionality of different services into single service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working on an application which has around 20 tabs(tabs and subtabs) each time i click on a tab, a request is sent to the server to fetch data. 
(ex: "https://localhost:8443/app/tabname/:id")

I had to write different services for each tab, for example :

```
 Tab1 has tab1-service.js which makes a restangular call 
"Restangular.one("tab1",id).get("...");"

 tab2 i wrote tab2-service.js with similar functionality
"Restangular.one("tab2",id).get("...");"
```

IS it possible to have an object in which i can pass the name of tab and retrieve it in service ?? (this will reduce the code a lot)
Need suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can make a tab service and call it with the parameters for each tab.

```
    app.factory("tabService", function(){
 return {
    getTab: getTab
 };

 function getTab(tabName, tabId)
 {
    return Restangular.one(tabName,tabId).get("...");
 }
});
```

and use it like this

```
   app.controller("myController", ["tabService", function(tabService){

     var tab = tabService.getTab("tab1", 1);
}]);
```

Hope this helps.